# adjust the size of the text label in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

Im trying to adjust the text size accoridng to country size, so the text will be inside the boardes of the copuntry.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df=pd.read_csv('regional-be-daily-latest.csv', header = 1)

fig = px.choropleth(df, locations='Code', color='Track Name')
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})

fig.add_scattergeo(

  locations = df['Code'],
  text = df['Track Name'],
  mode = 'text',
)

fig.show()
```

For the visualiztion:

[image]

The text for orange country is inside the boardes of the country but the text to label the blue countrry is bigger.

Best would be to adjust the size so it will not exceed the boardes of the country

Comment: Have you found a solution or you still require help on that issue? if you solved it, please add the solution :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can set the font size using the update_layout function and specifying the font's size by passing the dictionary in the font parameter.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df=pd.read_csv('regional-be-daily-latest.csv', header = 1)

fig = px.choropleth(df, locations='Code', color='Track Name')
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})

fig.add_scattergeo(

  locations = df['Code'],
  text = df['Track Name'],
  mode = 'text',
)


fig.update_layout(
    font=dict(
        family="Courier New, monospace",
        size=18,  # Set the font size here
        color="RebeccaPurple"
    )
)

fig.show()
```

Comment: hey, unfortunately not working as i want

Answer (score 1):

[Text and Annotations in Python](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/)

You can [Controll Text Size with uniformtext](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/#controlling-text-size-with-uniformtext) like this

```
fig.update_traces(textposition='inside')
fig.update_layout(uniformtext_minsize=8, uniformtext_mode='hide')
```

or
[Controll Maximum Text Size](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/#controlling-maximum-text-size)

```
fig.update_traces(textposition='inside', textfont_size=14)
```

These ways you don't change axis and label font sizes.